# How do you format the date as a two digit year? (ex. "10.12.10" instead of "10.12.2010")

Tags: date-time

I did a pretty thorough search and found a couple of closed (and unanswered) topics on the WP forums. Does anyone know if this is possible? The codex doesn't specify this as an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a lowercase y for a 2 digit year.

For example (l, F j, Y) -->  returns, Friday, September 24, 2004

and  (l, F j, y) ---> returns Friday, September 24, 04

Comment: Gah... I feel stupid. Thank you so much. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Here is [the full (I think) list of valid date/time parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to pass to the_date() and/or the_time().